# Data sync algorithm based on timing

Tags: multithreading, data-synchronization

I have a problem related to data sync:

I have a source that sequentially emit data to my computer. Assume we call each data named V. V has a unique ID and contains 2 items A and B, each A or B has only a string data call ID. B is optional, that is a V can contain only A.
V will emit A and B to computer independently via 2 tcp sockets or 2 message queues. ID of V is not emited and has no sense for sync, only be used for manual check later.
Interval delay between each V can vary from minimum 500ms to 15 minutes.

E.g, source V1(A1, B1), V2(A2), V3(A3, B3)
These emit to computer via 2 queues QA(A1, A2, A3) and QB(B1, B3).

How can I sync data A and B of V at the consumers of 2 those queues as source entry sequence order?
Required: B must be sync to exact V, A can be in wrong V. E.g, after syncing, V1 must contains B1, V2 must have no B. V3 must contains B3.

Is there any sync algorithm based on timing for solving this problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok as long as we know that there is an ID for each V  it is trival to build a data persistence level to take care of data syncing.

I would use a caching database ( e.g redis) to store each V emmited. On each socket listen for a new value A or B, check if the corresponding V exist in the DB, if it doesn't exist create a new key using V ID, else if it exist add the newly received value to the relevant V.

Using a different layer for data syncing will give you the advantage of not having to worry about the interval delay between each V.

**Update**:

Since we don't have any source of info to link the emitted data i.e A and B other than time, I would still use Redis to create a new entry for each V whenever A is sent , then on the socket listening for B data I will have a notify function if a new A has been registered, if that function triggered I will fetch the new entry and place a timer, if a new B data received I will place it with that entry. The notify function  will place a timer too, so if it exceeds the max time of 15 minutes. It will not use that entry,  or if a new A has been registered it will use the new one instead of the one fetched before.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But ID of V is not emited to computer, only A and B are. ID of V is only for manual check later and have no sense for sync.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment because I had to join another project. I will study your idea. Thank you very much.